# How to pass value from parent component to child component (react)

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm new to learning React, and am trying to pass on a value that I'm getting from user input inside of my `ParentComponent` (via input box) into its `ChildComponent` - which I'll use the user input value to run an AJAX call.

I thought that by replacing the state in the `ParentComponent` would work - but I'm still not able to grab it in the `ChildComponent`.

I also only want the `ChildComponent` to run/render only after receiving the input value from the `ParentComponent` (so that I can run the AJAX call and then render...).

Any tips?

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
     getInitialState: function() {
         return {data: []};
     },

    handleSearch: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var userInput = $('#userInput').val();
        this.replaceState({data: userInput});
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id="userInput"></input>
                    <button onClick={this.handleSearch}>Search</button>
                </form>
                <ChildComponent />
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
          );
        }
    });

var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
        return <div> User's Input: {this.state.data} </div>
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should pass parent state as a prop to your child: Change your childcomponent inside parent render to:

```
<ChildComponent foo={this.state.data} />
```

And then you can access it inside ChildComponent through `this.props.foo`.

Explanation: Inside ChildComponent, `this.state.someData` refers to ChildComponent state. And your child doesn't have state. (Which is fine by the way)

Also: `this.setState()` is probably better than `this.replaceState()`.

And better to initialize parent state with

```
return { data : null };
```